# Issue with akka application inside docker container

Tags: docker, akka, spray

We have a akka application running in production in a non clustered mode ( doesn't akka clustering ). 
We are trying to dockerize this application and running into an issue. We are using docker host networking and for various other reasons we are not yet ready to use other types of networking.

Application binds to 0.0.0.0 interface on port 9080 and does a simple http healthcheck on itself. 
This healthcheck is failing because we are seeing a connection reset error. We are seeing this only inside docker container.

During startup time application gets bound to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9080. 
2018-04-13T08:29:54.921-0700 [INFO ] - Bound to /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9080

akka logs:

```
2018-04-13T08:34:25.311-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpListener            [15:34:25.311UTC] - New connection accepted
2018-04-13T08:34:25.312-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.SelectionHandler       [15:34:25.312UTC] - now supervising Actor[akka://appname/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$d/12#394551476]
2018-04-13T08:34:25.312-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpIncomingConnection  [15:34:25.312UTC] - started (akka.io.TcpIncomingConnection@1dafecc7)
2018-04-13T08:34:25.312-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpIncomingConnection  [15:34:25.312UTC] - now watched by Actor[akka://appname/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$d#992175932]
2018-04-13T08:34:25.312-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpIncomingConnection  [15:34:25.312UTC] - now watched by Actor[akka://appname/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0/88#-1187840999]
2018-04-13T08:34:25.313-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.SelectionHandler       [15:34:25.313UTC] - now supervising Actor[akka://appname/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$h/11#789402148]
2018-04-13T08:34:25.313-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection  [15:34:25.313UTC] - started (akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection@62c77639)
2018-04-13T08:34:25.313-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection  [15:34:25.313UTC] - now watched by Actor[akka://appname/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$h#227381172]
2018-04-13T08:34:25.313-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection  [15:34:25.313UTC] - Attempting connection to [/0.0.0.0:9080]
2018-04-13T08:34:25.313-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpListener            [15:34:25.313UTC] - New connection accepted
2018-04-13T08:34:25.313-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection  [15:34:25.313UTC] - Connection established to [/0.0.0.0:9080]
2018-04-13T08:34:25.314-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection  [15:34:25.314UTC] - now watched by Actor[akka://appname/user/IO-HTTP/group-0/52#1518564728]
2018-04-13T08:34:25.314-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.SelectionHandler       [15:34:25.314UTC] - now supervising Actor[akka://appname/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$h/12#1641348988]
2018-04-13T08:34:25.314-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpIncomingConnection  [15:34:25.314UTC] - started (akka.io.TcpIncomingConnection@65bac45)
2018-04-13T08:34:25.314-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpIncomingConnection  [15:34:25.314UTC] - now watched by Actor[akka://appname/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$h#227381172]
2018-04-13T08:34:26.327-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpIncomingConnection  [15:34:26.327UTC] - now watched by Actor[akka://appname/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0/89#-1079090421]
2018-04-13T08:34:26.327-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpIncomingConnection  [15:34:26.327UTC] - stopped
2018-04-13T08:34:26.327-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection  [15:34:26.327UTC] - Closing connection due to IO error java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
2018-04-13T08:34:26.327-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection  [15:34:26.327UTC] - stopped
2018-04-13T08:34:26.328-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpIncomingConnection  [15:34:26.328UTC] - stopped
```

Spray logs:

```
2018-04-13T08:35:39.168-0700 - Dispatching GET request to http://10.4.4.178:9080/admin/health to handler Actor[akka://appname/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$b/20#-595408603]
2018-04-13T08:35:45.296-0700 - Dispatching GET request to http://10.4.4.178:9080/admin/health to handler Actor[akka://appname/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$d/19#721242322]
2018-04-13T08:35:51.372-0700 - Dispatching GET request to http://10.4.4.178:9080/admin/health to handler Actor[akka://appname/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$c/16#1510321611]
2018-04-13T08:35:57.436-0700 - Dispatching GET request to http://10.4.4.178:9080/admin/health to handler Actor[akka://appname/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$g/22#1994752981]
2018-04-13T08:36:03.622-0700 - Dispatching GET request to http://10.4.4.178:9080/admin/health to handler Actor[akka://appname/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$f/20#-1450294853]
```

Healthcheck logs

```
2018-04-13T08:32:53.356-0700 [INFO ] - [BEGIN] Health check
2018-04-13T08:32:53.356-0700 [DEBUG] - Memory    : SUCCESS
2018-04-13T08:32:54.378-0700 [DEBUG] - HTTP      : FAILURE, spray.can.Http$ConnectionException: ErrorClosed(Connection reset by peer)
2018-04-13T08:32:54.378-0700 [ERROR] - spray.can.Http$ConnectionException: ErrorClosed(Connection reset by peer)
    at spray.can.client.HttpHostConnectionSlot.reportDisconnection(HttpHostConnectionSlot.scala:228)
    at spray.can.client.HttpHostConnectionSlot$$anonfun$connected$1.applyOrElse(HttpHostConnectionSlot.scala:161)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at spray.can.client.HttpHostConnectionSlot.aroundReceive(HttpHostConnectionSlot.scala:33)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke_aroundBody0(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell$AjcClosure1.run(ActorCell.scala:1)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
    at akka.instrumentation.ActorCellInstrumentation.aroundBehaviourInvoke(ActorCellInstrumentation.scala:66)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:483)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

2018-04-13T08:32:54.378-0700 [INFO ] - [END  ] Status: Failed (1022 ms)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java-base:0.2.3
EXPOSE 9080 9081
ENV MAIN_CLASS="akka.kernel.Main" \
    ADMIN_PORT="9080" \
    HEALTHCHECK_URI="/admin/health" \
    TEMPLATES="/app/templates/override.settings.tmpl:/app/conf/override.settings /app/templates/environment.conf.tmpl:/app/conf/environment.conf" \
    JMX_PORT="9081" \
    APP_NAME="appname" \
    APP_VERSION="1.34.0" \
    CLASSPATH="/app/conf" \
    ENV_FILES="/app/conf/override.settings" \
    INSTRUMENTATION_PATH="/app/ext" \
    JVM_MISC_OPTS="-Dpid=1 \
                  -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///app/conf/log4j.xml \
                  -javaagent:\${INSTRUMENTATION_PATH}/aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar \
                  -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///app/conf/log4j.xml \
                  -Dlogs.dir=/app/logs \
                  -Dakka.home=/app \
                  -Dakka.kernel.quiet=false \
                  -Dconfig.file=/app/conf/environment.conf" \
    MAIN_CLASS_ARGS=appname.Boot
ADD ext /app/ext
ADD deps /app/libs
ADD templates/ /app/templates/
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  appname:
    container_name: appname
    image: appname:1.34.0
    network_mode: host
    restart: unless-stopped
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65535
        hard: 65535
    environment:
      UID:
      SDLC_ENVIRONMENT:
      REGION:
      PARTITION:
      TAGS:
      INTERNAL_IP:
      CONSUL_ADDRESS:
      DOCKER_GID:
      MAIN_CLASS_ARGS: appname.Boot
    volumes:
      - "./logs:/app/logs"
```

Akka Config:

```
2018-04-17T11:39:17.753-0700 [DEBUG] akka.event.EventStream         [18:39:17.713UTC] - Default Loggers started
2018-04-17T11:39:17.755-0700 [INFO ] akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl     [18:39:17.738UTC] - {
    "akka" : {
        "actor" : {
            "creation-timeout" : "20s",
            "debug" : {
                "autoreceive" : "off",
                "event-stream" : "off",
                "fsm" : "off",
                "lifecycle" : "off",
                "receive" : "off",
                "router-misconfiguration" : "off",
                "unhandled" : "off"
            },
            "default-dispatcher" : {
                "attempt-teamwork" : "on",
                "default-executor" : {
                    "fallback" : "fork-join-executor"
                },
                "executor" : "default-executor",
                "fork-join-executor" : {
                    "parallelism-factor" : 16,
                    "parallelism-min" : 8,
                    "task-peeking-mode" : "FIFO"
                },
                "mailbox-requirement" : "",
                "shutdown-timeout" : "1s",
                "thread-pool-executor" : {
                    "allow-core-timeout" : "on",
                    "core-pool-size-factor" : 3,
                    "core-pool-size-max" : 64,
                    "core-pool-size-min" : 8,
                    "keep-alive-time" : "60s",
                    "max-pool-size-factor" : 3,
                    "max-pool-size-max" : 64,
                    "max-pool-size-min" : 8,
                    "task-queue-size" : -1,
                    "task-queue-type" : "linked"
                },
                "throughput" : 1,
                "throughput-deadline-time" : "0ms",
                "type" : "Dispatcher"
            },
            "default-mailbox" : {
                "mailbox-capacity" : 1000,
                "mailbox-push-timeout-time" : "10s",
                "mailbox-type" : "akka.dispatch.UnboundedMailbox",
                "stash-capacity" : -1
            },
            "deployment" : {
                "default" : {
                    "dispatcher" : "",
                    "mailbox" : "",
                    "nr-of-instances" : 1,
                    "resizer" : {
                        "backoff-rate" : 0.1,
                        "backoff-threshold" : 0.3,
                        "enabled" : "off",
                        "lower-bound" : 1,
                        "messages-per-resize" : 10,
                        "pressure-threshold" : 1,
                        "rampup-rate" : 0.2,
                        "upper-bound" : 10
                    },
                    "routees" : {
                        "paths" : []
                    },
                    "router" : "from-code",
                    "tail-chopping-router" : {
                        "interval" : "10 milliseconds"
                    },
                    "virtual-nodes-factor" : 10,
                    "within" : "5 seconds"
                }
            },
            "dsl" : {
                "default-timeout" : "5s",
                "inbox-size" : 1000
            },
            "guardian-supervisor-strategy" : "akka.actor.DefaultSupervisorStrategy",
            "mailbox" : {
                "bounded-deque-based" : {
                    "mailbox-type" : "akka.dispatch.BoundedDequeBasedMailbox"
                },
                "bounded-queue-based" : {
                    "mailbox-type" : "akka.dispatch.BoundedMailbox"
                },
                "requirements" : {
                    "akka.dispatch.BoundedDequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics" : "akka.actor.mailbox.bounded-deque-based",
                    "akka.dispatch.BoundedMessageQueueSemantics" : "akka.actor.mailbox.bounded-queue-based",
                    "akka.dispatch.DequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics" : "akka.actor.mailbox.unbounded-deque-based",
                    "akka.dispatch.MultipleConsumerSemantics" : "akka.actor.mailbox.unbounded-queue-based",
                    "akka.dispatch.UnboundedDequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics" : "akka.actor.mailbox.unbounded-deque-based",
                    "akka.dispatch.UnboundedMessageQueueSemantics" : "akka.actor.mailbox.unbounded-queue-based"
                },
                "unbounded-deque-based" : {
                    "mailbox-type" : "akka.dispatch.UnboundedDequeBasedMailbox"
                },
                "unbounded-queue-based" : {
                    "mailbox-type" : "akka.dispatch.UnboundedMailbox"
                }
            },
            "provider" : "akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider",
            "reaper-interval" : "5s",
            "router" : {
                "type-mapping" : {
                    "balancing-pool" : "akka.routing.BalancingPool",
                    "broadcast-group" : "akka.routing.BroadcastGroup",
                    "broadcast-pool" : "akka.routing.BroadcastPool",
                    "consistent-hashing-group" : "akka.routing.ConsistentHashingGroup",
                    "consistent-hashing-pool" : "akka.routing.ConsistentHashingPool",
                    "from-code" : "akka.routing.NoRouter",
                    "random-group" : "akka.routing.RandomGroup",
                    "random-pool" : "akka.routing.RandomPool",
                    "round-robin-group" : "akka.routing.RoundRobinGroup",
                    "round-robin-pool" : "akka.routing.RoundRobinPool",
                    "scatter-gather-group" : "akka.routing.ScatterGatherFirstCompletedGroup",
                    "scatter-gather-pool" : "akka.routing.ScatterGatherFirstCompletedPool",
                    "smallest-mailbox-pool" : "akka.routing.SmallestMailboxPool",
                    "tail-chopping-group" : "akka.routing.TailChoppingGroup",
                    "tail-chopping-pool" : "akka.routing.TailChoppingPool"
                }
            },
            "serialization-bindings" : {
                "[B" : "bytes",
                "java.io.Serializable" : "java"
            },
            "serialize-creators" : "off",
            "serialize-messages" : "off",
            "serializers" : {
                "bytes" : "akka.serialization.ByteArraySerializer",
                "java" : "akka.serialization.JavaSerializer"
            },
            "typed" : {
                "timeout" : "5s"
            },
            "unstarted-push-timeout" : "10s"
        },
        "daemonic" : "off",
        "extensions" : [],
        "home" : "/app",
        "io" : {
            "pinned-dispatcher" : {
                "executor" : "thread-pool-executor",
                "thread-pool-executor" : {
                    "allow-core-pool-timeout" : "off",
                    "allow-core-timeout" : "off"
                },
                "type" : "PinnedDispatcher"
            },
            "tcp" : {
                "batch-accept-limit" : 10,
                "direct-buffer-pool-limit" : 1000,
                "direct-buffer-size" : "128 KiB",
                "file-io-dispatcher" : "akka.actor.default-dispatcher",
                "file-io-transferTo-limit" : "512 KiB",
                "finish-connect-retries" : 5,
                "management-dispatcher" : "akka.actor.default-dispatcher",
                "max-channels" : 256000,
                "max-received-message-size" : "unlimited",
                "nr-of-selectors" : 10,
                "register-timeout" : "5s",
                "selector-association-retries" : 10,
                "selector-dispatcher" : "akka.io.pinned-dispatcher",
                "trace-logging" : "off",
                "windows-connection-abort-workaround-enabled" : "off",
                "worker-dispatcher" : "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"
            },
            "udp" : {
                "direct-buffer-pool-limit" : 1000,
                "direct-buffer-size" : "128 KiB",
                "management-dispatcher" : "akka.actor.default-dispatcher",
                "max-channels" : 4096,
                "nr-of-selectors" : 1,
                "receive-throughput" : 3,
                "received-message-size-limit" : "unlimited",
                "select-timeout" : "infinite",
                "selector-association-retries" : 10,
                "selector-dispatcher" : "akka.io.pinned-dispatcher",
                "trace-logging" : "off",
                "worker-dispatcher" : "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"
            },
            "udp-connected" : {
                "direct-buffer-pool-limit" : 1000,
                "direct-buffer-size" : "128 KiB",
                "management-dispatcher" : "akka.actor.default-dispatcher",
                "max-channels" : 4096,
                "nr-of-selectors" : 1,
                "receive-throughput" : 3,
                "received-message-size-limit" : "unlimited",
                "select-timeout" : "infinite",
                "selector-association-retries" : 10,
                "selector-dispatcher" : "akka.io.pinned-dispatcher",
                "trace-logging" : "off",
                "worker-dispatcher" : "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"
            }
        },
        "jvm-exit-on-fatal-error" : "on",
        "kernel" : {
            "quiet" : "true"
        },
        "log-config-on-start" : "on",
        "log-dead-letters" : 10,
        "log-dead-letters-during-shutdown" : "on",
        "logger-startup-timeout" : "5s",
        "loggers" : [
            "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"
        ],
        "loglevel" : "DEBUG",
        "scheduler" : {
            "implementation" : "akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler",
            "shutdown-timeout" : "5s",
            "tick-duration" : "10ms",
            "ticks-per-wheel" : 512
        },
        "stdout-loglevel" : "WARNING",
        "version" : "2.3.16"
    },
    "awt" : {
        "toolkit" : "sun.awt.X11.XToolkit"
    },
    "java" : {
        "version" : "1.8.0_121",
        "vm" : {
            "info" : "mixed mode",
            "name" : "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM",
            "specification" : {
                "name" : "Java Virtual Machine Specification",
                "vendor" : "Oracle Corporation",
                "version" : "1.8"
            },
            "vendor" : "Oracle Corporation",
            "version" : "25.121-b13"
        }
    }
    "pid" : "1",
    "spray" : {
        "can" : {
            "client" : {
                "chunkless-streaming" : "off",
                "connecting-timeout" : "10s",
                "idle-timeout" : "610s",
                "max-encryption-chunk-size" : "1m",
                "parsing" : {
                    "header-cache" : {
                        "Content-MD5" : 0,
                        "Date" : 0,
                        "If-Match" : 0,
                        "If-Modified-Since" : 0,
                        "If-None-Match" : 0,
                        "If-Range" : 0,
                        "If-Unmodified-Since" : 0,
                        "User-Agent" : 32,
                        "default" : 12
                    },
                    "illegal-header-warnings" : "off",
                    "incoming-auto-chunking-threshold-size" : "infinite",
                    "max-chunk-ext-length" : 256,
                    "max-chunk-size" : "1m",
                    "max-content-length" : "8m",
                    "max-header-count" : 64,
                    "max-header-name-length" : 64,
                    "max-header-value-length" : "8k",
                    "max-response-reason-length" : 64,
                    "max-uri-length" : "2k",
                    "ssl-session-info-header" : "off",
                    "uri-parsing-mode" : "strict"
                },
                "proxy" : {
                    "http" : "default",
                    "https" : "default"
                },
                "reaping-cycle" : "250 ms",
                "request-header-size-hint" : 512,
                "request-timeout" : "605s",
                "response-chunk-aggregation-limit" : "5m",
                "ssl-tracing" : "off",
                "user-agent-header" : "spray-can/1.3.2"
            },
            "connection-dispatcher" : "akka.actor.default-dispatcher",
            "host-connector" : {
                "client" : {
                    "chunkless-streaming" : "off",
                    "connecting-timeout" : "10s",
                    "idle-timeout" : "60 s",
                    "max-encryption-chunk-size" : "1m",
                    "parsing" : {
                        "header-cache" : {
                            "Content-MD5" : 0,
                            "Date" : 0,
                            "If-Match" : 0,
                            "If-Modified-Since" : 0,
                            "If-None-Match" : 0,
                            "If-Range" : 0,
                            "If-Unmodified-Since" : 0,
                            "User-Agent" : 32,
                            "default" : 12
                        },
                        "illegal-header-warnings" : "on",
                        "incoming-auto-chunking-threshold-size" : "infinite",
                        "max-chunk-ext-length" : 256,
                        "max-chunk-size" : "1m",
                        "max-content-length" : "8m",
                        "max-header-count" : 64,
                        "max-header-name-length" : 64,
                        "max-header-value-length" : "8k",
                        "max-response-reason-length" : 64,
                        "max-uri-length" : "2k",
                        "ssl-session-info-header" : "off",
                        "uri-parsing-mode" : "strict"
                    },
                    "proxy" : {
                        "http" : "default",
                        "https" : "default"
                    },
                    "reaping-cycle" : "250 ms",
                    "request-header-size-hint" : 512,
                    "request-timeout" : "20 s",
                    "response-chunk-aggregation-limit" : "1m",
                    "ssl-tracing" : "off",
                    "user-agent-header" : "spray-can/1.3.2"
                },
                "idle-timeout" : "30 s",
                "max-connections" : 100,
                "max-redirects" : 0,
                "max-retries" : 0,
                "pipelining" : "off"
            },
            "host-connector-dispatcher" : "akka.actor.default-dispatcher",
            "listener-dispatcher" : "akka.actor.default-dispatcher",
            "manager-dispatcher" : "akka.actor.default-dispatcher",
            "parsing" : {
                "header-cache" : {
                    "Content-MD5" : 0,
                    "Date" : 0,
                    "If-Match" : 0,
                    "If-Modified-Since" : 0,
                    "If-None-Match" : 0,
                    "If-Range" : 0,
                    "If-Unmodified-Since" : 0,
                    "User-Agent" : 32,
                    "default" : 12
                },
                "illegal-header-warnings" : "off",
                "incoming-auto-chunking-threshold-size" : "infinite",
                "max-chunk-ext-length" : 256,
                "max-chunk-size" : "1m",
                "max-content-length" : "8m",
                "max-header-count" : 64,
                "max-header-name-length" : 64,
                "max-header-value-length" : "8k",
                "max-response-reason-length" : 64,
                "max-uri-length" : "2k",
                "ssl-session-info-header" : "off",
                "uri-parsing-mode" : "strict"
            },
            "server" : {
                "automatic-back-pressure-handling" : "on",
                "back-pressure" : {
                    "noack-rate" : 10,
                    "reading-low-watermark" : "infinite"
                },
                "bind-timeout" : "1s",
                "chunkhandler-registration-timeout" : "500 ms",
                "chunkless-streaming" : "off",
                "default-host-header" : "",
                "idle-timeout" : "610s",
                "max-encryption-chunk-size" : "1m",
                "parsing" : {
                    "header-cache" : {
                        "Content-MD5" : 0,
                        "Date" : 0,
                        "If-Match" : 0,
                        "If-Modified-Since" : 0,
                        "If-None-Match" : 0,
                        "If-Range" : 0,
                        "If-Unmodified-Since" : 0,
                        "User-Agent" : 32,
                        "default" : 12
                    },
                    "illegal-header-warnings" : "off",
                    "incoming-auto-chunking-threshold-size" : "infinite",
                    "max-chunk-ext-length" : 256,
                    "max-chunk-size" : "1m",
                    "max-content-length" : "8m",
                    "max-header-count" : 64,
                    "max-header-name-length" : 64,
                    "max-header-value-length" : "16k",
                    "max-response-reason-length" : 64,
                    "max-uri-length" : "2k",
                    "ssl-session-info-header" : "off",
                    "uri-parsing-mode" : "relaxed-with-raw-query"
                },
                "parsing-error-abort-timeout" : "2s",
                "pipelining-limit" : 1,
                "raw-request-uri-header" : "off",
                "reaping-cycle" : "250 ms",
                "registration-timeout" : "1s",
                "remote-address-header" : "on",
                "request-chunk-aggregation-limit" : "1m",
                "request-timeout" : "605s",
                "response-header-size-hint" : 512,
                "server-header" : "BlueJeans Proxy",
                "ssl-encryption" : "off",
                "ssl-tracing" : "off",
                "stats-support" : "on",
                "timeout-handler" : "",
                "timeout-timeout" : "2 s",
                "transparent-head-requests" : "on",
                "unbind-timeout" : "1s",
                "verbose-error-messages" : "off"
            },
            "settings-group-dispatcher" : "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"
        }
        "version" : "1.3.2"
    }
}

2018-04-17T11:39:20.980-0700 [DEBUG] akka.io.TcpListener            [18:39:20.979UTC] - Successfully bound to /10.4.4.178:9080
```

Versions: 
akka - 2.3.0
spray - 1.3.2
running on alpine linux inside a docker container.

Any pointers would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the docker and/or docker-compose files

Comment: @Shoan  Updated with docker and docker-compose files

Comment: Post the akka config file also

Comment: @Phani, still waiting on configs to be updated in the question

Comment: Updated with Akka config.

Answer (score 2):

In the docker-compose file, define port mapping under appname.

```
ports:
    9080:9080
```

Comment: I am using host networking, so port mapping is not supported.